# Ouath2 + jwt and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I want to implement in backend rest safely in oauth2 + jwt.

I want to implement the following authentication flow in spring boot, but I am not sure how to do it:
1. The user is authenticated.
2. That request is received and with that login and password a ws that validates the credentials is attacked.
3. If it is correct, a series of data and permissions are searched in the database
4. If it is correct, access is granted and the jwt token is generated

I'm lost with this and as much as I read I can't know how I can do it.
Any manual or post I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your own (a custom) Auth server or is the plan to allow users to authenticate via a provider such as Google, Facebook etc?  If its the later, then you cannot expect to receive user / password credentials at all so you might have misunderstood the OAuth flow. You will typically receive an 'Authorization code' from the provider (e.g. Google).

Also, what do you mean by *"a ws that validates the credentials is attacked"*?

This [Google use-case diagram](https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/webflow.png) depicts a common flow.  It's part of [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Either way, Spring Boot does not itself deal with OAuth / security, but it has a tight 
integration with [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) which is a good security framework to use, especially as you're already using Spring. Spring Security can handle OAuth, JWT etc.

A couple of guides that may help to get you started:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt
- https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/